# Help identifying and repairing a wrought iron Suffolk latch

Tags: doors, latches, front-door

I’m looking for help identifying the source of and refurbishing this front door wrought iron latch and handle.  I believe it’s called a Suffolk latch.  The groove where the lever piece rests on the handle piece inside the door has worn away from use, so the lever is a bit loose and falls out of position.  I have tried gluing various plastic and metal shims to hold the lever centered in place, but they all eventually fall off.

Any leads on how to fix or sources of antique replacement latches like this in the US, specifically Westchester County, New York or online.

[image: Suffolk latch]

Comment: "Where do I buy ___" is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @FreeMan - thanks.  I’m new here so please forgive the potential breech. However, I’m not sure this qualifies as off-topic, as the answer would not be a link to Amazon, since this is a unique handmade part.  An ideal scenario would be someone recognizing the origin of this handle or at least a discussion of how to repair these kinds of latches and whether anyone here has more inside knowledge about them.  I suppose I could have phrased the question that way.

Comment: 1) No worries, feel free to [edit] your question to indicate that. 2) Please use the site's built in image hosting - not everyone wants to click links to see pics. 3) Look locally for a metal smith as he would be the one most likely able to repair a custom built door lock. If you can't find one, try calling local woodworkers, looking for someone who specializes in doors and ask them if they have any idea who might make/repair wrought iron works like this.

Comment: Thanks for the patience and tips.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a replacement, try an architectural recycling place. It'll cost you an arm and a leg, since that's all hip & trendy these days, but they'd be likely to have something or direct you to someone who might.

Comment: Sounds like you need to weld some metal back into place and file it to suit.

Comment: Here we have people specializing in buying old doors and windows and reselling them. Look for them and buy a door to get the handle. Similarly there are places that buy old latches etc to resell.